# Line chart for aggregate transactions in various types (netting off)

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got two large separate dataframes tracking aggregate transactions in a particular items.
Df1 follows this structure:

```
structure(list(NAME = c("Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", 
"Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", 
"Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", 
"Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", 
"Stock 2014", "Stock 2014"), Transaction_DATE = structure(c(11893, 
11983, 12167, 12216, 12263, 12893, 13075, 13894, 13985, 14174, 
14265, 14405, 14540, 14778, 14855, 15266, 15478, 15538, 15562, 
15666), class = "Date"), TRANSACTION = c(2800, 2750, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 360, 289, 135, 405, 1845, 1602, 5490.409, 4880.86, 4399.53, 
4122.574, 793, 1500, 539, 1500, -332.3), Termination_DATE = structure(c(16320, 
16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 
16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 16320, 
16320), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Df1 is the main dataframe for this task, and tracks items that were available for sale (denoted by the column "TRANSACTION"). "TRANSACTION" is not an aggregated column (nor is it really representative of a transaction), it simply represents new issues of "Stock 2014" that were available for sale on each date; so the first entry was the first time the item was available for sale to customers. At 2002-10-23, an additional 2750.000 was available for sale (along with the original 2800.000 available on 2002-07-25).

Termination_DATE represents the date the good is no longer sellable, and therefore the time series data needs to end there.

Df2 represents the number of sales made by customers on each date:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1236729600, 1237334400, 1237939200, 
1238544000, 1239148800, 1239753600, 1240272000, 1240963200, 1241568000, 
1242172800, 1242777600, 1243382400, 1245196800, 1245801600, 1257897600, 
1259107200, 1260230400, 1262736000, 1263945600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), NAME = c("Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", 
"Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", 
"Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", 
"Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", "Stock 2014", 
"Stock 2014"), Proceeds = c(4078.501279, 4250.769106, 336.426711, 
1015.964789, 1482.626306, 2419.852908, 6371.6269, 3901.862847, 
964.90766, 7455.621856, 2511.91081, 2233.596381, 2658.115097, 
2177.589872, 128.715088, 923.391173, 67.389718, 916.832833, 113.312322
)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

"Proceeds" represents the transaction.

So what I want to do is to create timeline of each item's net unsold goods as a time series between the first transaction_DATE on df1, and the Termination_DATE, thereby taking account of the date and transactions listed on df2.

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this (apologies if unclear, English is not a first language).

EDIT: I should probably mention that there isn't just one item available for sale (it's a large dataframe, containing more items than just "Stock 2014", so a solution would need to take account of that).

EDIT2: Fixed the strange dput output error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your dataframes together, make `Proceeds` negative, and compute a cumulative sum to get a running net total.

NB, it's best to provide example data that captures all your requirements. I added a second `NAME` to your data to account for the multiple-items requirement.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_both <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(
    Transaction_DATE = as.Date(Date), 
    TRANSACTION = -1 * Proceeds,
    .keep = "unused"
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows(df1) %>% 
  arrange(NAME, Transaction_DATE) %>% 
  group_by(NAME) %>% 
  mutate(Net_Unsold = cumsum(TRANSACTION)) %>% 
  ungroup() 

ggplot(df_both, aes(Transaction_DATE, Net_Unsold)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = .25, color = "gray30") +
  geom_line(aes(color = NAME)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

*Expanded example data:*

```
set.seed(13)

df1 <- bind_rows(
  df1, 
  mutate(
    df1, 
    NAME = "Stock 2015", 
    Transaction_DATE = Transaction_DATE + 365,
    Termination_DATE = Termination_DATE + 365,
    TRANSACTION = TRANSACTION + rnorm(n(), sd = 500)
  )
)

df2 <- bind_rows(
  df2,
  mutate(
    df2, 
    NAME = "Stock 2015", 
    Date = Date + 365,
    Proceeds = Proceeds + rnorm(n(), sd = 500)
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works for the df1 and df2 added but doesn't work for the much larger df. Only reason I gave a cut-down version was because of the size of the dfs (df1 is 2k, while df2 is 7.6k)